# what's the proper use of kibana wildcards?

Tags: kibana

I have Kibana v. 4.0.2.

If I make a query like this

```
rdp:(DPRADUSH or DPPIR)
```

I am able to see my data:

[image]

but if I try a wildcard

```
rdp:DP*
```

it breaks.

[image]

how can I use it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```json
{"wildcard":{"rdp":"DP*"}}
```

Comment: Very much appreciate the sample, really nice!